# Importing/Loading .csv file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

Trying to import/load a .csv file into a table.  Help?!!

Best

Getting ....

Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

The wait operation timed out

Comment: An "FF"? What is a FF?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18357.0
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.100.44091.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      15.0.19260.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      10.0.19042

Comment: FF= Flat file, e.g., .csv or .txt